# Flutter Firebase Push-Notification Icon on a android device sometimes grey, sometimes appear the icon

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, icons

I have a little challenge: We have implemented push-notification and it works finde. The Problem is, that on my Android device appears the Push-Icon, but on the Android device of my colleague, its only grey without our Icon. I have the same problem on the Android emulator, their appear the push notification, but without icon, only grey.
But on some real devices appears the icon, on some real devices it doesnt appears. What can I do?

Comment: Are you using SVG for the icon? I have noticed random problems rendering icons from SVG in Android.

Comment: I am using the typical png, it shows up an all phones, only one colleague with a xiaome 11 get a grey icon, not our company logo.